# Select maximum by row & column contributing maximum

Tags: sql-server

I have a data set which looks like

```
Group   abc   cde efg ...
PQR    70     60  50   
LMN    30     40  30
XYZ    70     80  90
```

My data set contains around 35000 row & 30000 columns.
I need to write a SQL Query so that It can pool maximum value & the column contributing maximum. My Sample output looks like

```
 Group      Max Column
     PQR    70  abc
     LMN    40  cde
     XYZ    90  efg
```

Can you suggest me how should I proceed ?

Comment: If you can use a programming language whose purpose is more oriented towards data manipulation (like python), it would be much easier and effective to carry out such kind of task. Attempting to do this in SQL translates into inacceptable inefficiency, given your volumes.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
    select Max(grp) grp,Max(abc) abc, Max(cde) cde,Max(efg) efg into #tmp2 from testtbl
    select * from #tmp2
    
    select grp,MX,qq from (select grp,abc,cde,efg from #tmp2) p
    UNPIVOT (qq for MX in (
    abc,cde,efg
    )
    ) as unpvt
```